# How to debug an upstart script that intermittently fails?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-12.04, boot, upstart

I have a process that I want to start as soon my system is `rebooted` by whatever means so I was using `upstart` script for that but sometimes what I am noticing is my process doesn't get started up during hard reboot (plugging off and starting the machine) so I think my upstart script is not getting kicked in after hard reboot. I believe there is no runlevel for Hard Reboot.

I am confuse that why sometimes during reboot it works, but sometimes it doesn't work. And how can I debug this out?

Below is my upstart script:

```
# sudo start helper
# sudo stop helper
# sudo status helper
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

chdir /data
respawn

pre-start script
  echo "[`date`] Agent Starting" >> /data/agent.log
  sleep 30
end script

post-stop script
  echo "[`date`] Agent Stopping" >> /data/agent.log
  sleep 30
end script

limit core unlimited unlimited
limit nofile 100000 100000
setuid goldy
exec python helper.py
```

Is there any way to debug this out what's happening? I can easily reproduce this I believe. Any pointers on what I can do here?

**Note:**

During reboot sometimes I see the logging that I have in `pre-start` script but sometimes I don't see the logging at all after reboot and that means my upstart script was not triggered. Is there anything I need to change on runlevel to make it work?

I have a VM which is running in a Hypervisor and I am working with Ubuntu.

Comment: You might temporarily replace your `exec python helper.py` with something like: `script` `exec 2>>/path/to/log.txt` `set -x` `exec python helper.py` `end script`; that way you have a record in `/path/to/log.txt` of what happened during startup.

Comment: Can you check `/var/log/upstart` and see if that has something you need?

Comment: already checked and there is nothing in that I believe.

Comment: @david, do you see logs of other services in `/var/log/upstart` or the log itself is blank. Also run `dmesg` and see if you can find anything related to your service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your process running nicely, BUT during system startup many things go parallel.

IF mount (which makes available the `/data` folder) runs later than your `pre-start script` you will not see the "results" of `pre-start script`.

I suggest to move sleep 30 earlier (BTW 30 secs seems too looong):

```
pre-start script
  sleep 30 # sleep 10 should be enough
  echo "[`date`] Agent Starting" >> /data/agent.log
end script
```

Comment: ok will try this out but is there any other runlevel I can use that will guarantee to run my upstart script after every other upstart scripts has run (like mount)?

Comment: If you want to be sure your script runs after mount - more specific after local mounts,
enter
`start on local-filesystems` - this runs a bit later than `start on runlevel [2345]`

Comment: ok I tried by moving sleep just above and still it doesnt work few of the times so I have to start it manually. But what I have noticed is if I use this `start on stopped rc` instead of my original `start` line then it works always as per my testing. Do you know what could be the difference with my new changes?

Comment: @david, from my `/etc/init/rc.conf` Upstart config file: "
    # rc - System V runlevel compatibility
    #
    # This task runs the old System V-style rc script when changing between
    # runlevels. "

So your script starts now after all runlevel change script has finished.

Comment: So do you think that is helping me out? I am still not able to understand that why after switching to `start on stopped rc`, it works consistently always after reboot. Do you know why?

Comment: Any thought on this?

Comment: Ops. Yes. `start on stopped rc` means start when all rc script has ended. Means it starts as last (later than old S99* SystemV scripts). Meanwhile I do not understand why `sleep <many>` does not works - despite of the fact it is clumsy. I assumed problem is solved, as you mentioned...

Comment: Maybe it is waiting for something else to start but my upstart script is getting started earlier?